# Setting form (add) dialog to modeless

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm using free jqgrid 4-15-3 with guiStyle set to bootstrap. The problem is that the Add dialog launched from navGrid "+" button is a Model dialog by default. I have set the "model: fasle" in addParms but has no effect. Also failed in making changes in afterShowForm by setting jquery ui dialog "option" with "model", false. Below is the code snippet. What are the possible solutions?

```
$("#mygrid").jqGrid("navGrid", "#mygrid_nav", {add:true,...},{},
 { model:false,
   afterShowForm: function(form){
       $(form).closest(".ui-jqdialog").dialog("option", "model", false);
```

}
}

**Update:** Created a simple test as below, same result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
    <table id="tbl_test"></table>
    <div id="div_test_pager"></div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tbl_test").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            colNames: ['Col 1', 'Col 2'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'col1', index: 'col1', editable: true, width: 200 },
                { name: 'col2', editable: true, width: 100 }
            ],
            pager: "#div_test_pager",
            height: 200,
            caption: "Test"
        });
        $("#tbl_test").jqGrid("navGrid", "#div_test_pager",
            { edit: false, add: true, del: false, search: false, refresh: false }
            /*no difference*/
            //,{}, {modal: false}
        );
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Appreciate any help!

(Can Oleg or someone knows give a hint? Thanks a lot.)

Answer (score 0):

The word *model* you use is not correct - replace it with the word **moda**l in the settings and in the calling of the dialog function

Comment: Thanks. Same after both being corrected. In addition, calling dialog function in afterShowForm I got "can't call method on dialog prior to initialization" exception. Seems that there is no event handler I can write after dialog has been initialized in jqgrid?